# Having problem in building the solution for plugin for crm dynamics

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, dynamics-crm, ilmerge

I am trying to build a crm plugin solution.The solution has ILMerge therefore ive installed ILMerge using the nuget package but I am getting this build error in visual studio 2017.

```
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: log4net. at line 242
```

but at line 242 shown below there is no log4net code just this in my .csproj file

```
<Task InputAssemblies="@(MergeAsm)" OutputFile="$(MergedAssembly)" TargetKind="SameAsPrimaryAssembly" KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)" Internalize="false" DebugInfo="true" />
```

So how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was that the ddl files that i was trying to merge were also merged from other dll files. Therefore by adding the log4net in the reference in the solution solved the problem.